# React-native: download and unzip large language file

Tags: react-native

A multilingual react-native app. Each language bundle is ~50MB. It doesn't make sense to include all of them in a bundle. So, what do I do about it?

I assume the right way to go here is to download the respective language files upon language selection.
What do I do with it next? Do I suppose to store it using AsyncStorage or what?

Answer (score 11):

Briefly explaining, you will:

1. Store JSON as ZIP in Google Storage (save memory/bandwidth/time)
2. Unzip file to JSON (in RN)
3. Store JSON in AsyncStorage (in RN)
4. Retrieve from AsyncStorage (in RN)

[Dependencies Summary] You can do this, using these deps:

- [react-native](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native)
- [react-native-async-storage](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage)
- [rn-fetch-blob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-fetch-blob/v/0.10.13)
- [react-native-zip-archive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zip-archive)

Tip: Always store big language json in zip format (this can save up to 90% of size).

I made a quick test here: one 3.52MB json file, turned out a 26KB zipped file!

Let's consider that yours stored zip file, can be accessed by using a public url, eg: `https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/folder/lang-file.zip`.

Install and link all above RN deps, it's required to get this working.

Import the deps

```js
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
import { unzip } from 'react-native-zip-archive';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

1. Download the file using `rn-fetch-blob`. This can be done using:

```js
RNFetchBlob
.config({
  // add this option that makes response data to be stored as a file,
  // this is much more performant.
  fileCache : true,
})
.fetch('GET', 'http://www.example.com/file/example.zip', {
  //some headers ..
})
.then((res) => {
  // the temp file path
  console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())

  // Unzip will be called here!
  unzipDownloadFile(res.path(), (jsonFilePath) => {

    // Let's store this json.
    storeJSONtoAsyncStorage(jsonFilePath);

    // Done!
    // Now you can read the AsyncStorage everytime you need (using function bellow).
  });
});
```

2. [function] Unzip the downloaded file, using `react-native-zip-archive`:

```js
function unzipDownloadFile(target, cb) {
  const targetPath = target;
  const sourcePath = `${target}.json`;
  const charset = 'UTF-8';

  unzip(sourcePath, targetPath, charset)
  .then((path) => {
    console.log(`unzip completed at ${path}`)

    return cb(path);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
  });
}
```

3. [function] Store JSON in AsyncStorage:

```js
function storeJSONtoAsyncStorage (path) {
  RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(path, 'utf-8')
  .then((data) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem('myJSON', data);
  });
}
```

4. Retrieve JSON data from AsyncStorage (everytime you want):

```js
AsyncStorage.getItem('myJSON', (err, json) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    const myJSON = JSON.parse(json);

    // ... do what you need with you json lang file here...
  }
})
```

That's enough to get dynamic json lang files working in React Native.

I'm using this approach to give a similar feature to my i18n'ed project.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot. Is it possible to avoid asking for permission though? This approach requires permission on android

Comment: which app/cli did you use for zipping? I've tried mac's `zip`, `gzip`, `compress`.  `react-native-zip-archive` was unable to unzip any of them. With or without passwords.

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, this will require write permission on Android. However, the react-native-zip-archive don't tell about the permission in docs, but I think that to download external files, it need.

Comment: I'm zipping via linux using terminal, works good on last rn-zip-archive's version. You can try an online solution, as https://www.files2zip.com .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right to make the translation file downloadable.

You can store the downloaded file in the document directory of your app.
After that you can use a package to load the translations. For instance
https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js.

Comment: I need more detailed solution, in JS, no rails

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest taking a look at the i18n library which is a standard tool for internationalisation in JavaScript.

Consider taking a look at this [documentations page](https://www.i18next.com/how-to/add-or-load-translations) where you can find an option of loading a translation bundle or setting up a backend provider and hooking into it.

Also, to answer the storage question, if you do not plan on setting up a backend: AsyncStorage would be an appropriate place to store your key - translation text pairs.